# why it fail directing to a htm page from cshtml?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to direct to a htm page from the cshtml page, the code whitch i wrote in the cshtml page like this:

```
     <a href = "/content/all/@Model.PageLink" taget = '_blank'> More </a>
```

where the value of Model.PageLink is "test.htm".

when i click the "More", it allways failed: "http error 404: Bad Request". Who can tell whats wrong about it?

Comment: If you do "show source" on your page, what does the complete generated anchor look like?

Comment: I want it popup a new page tab, so i add the param "taget = "_blank""

Comment: When you run this page in your web browswer, can you right click on that page, select "View Source" and show the line with your `<a href..` it is easier to spot the problem if you look at the output!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the call into parenthesis:

```
<a href="/content/all/@(Model.PageLink)" taget="_blank">More</a>
```

Comment: I make a mistake, i add a extra "/" for the "PageLink" in databse, so the URL becomes the "/conten/all//test.htm". Thanks everybody!